# django-cms: Can I publish all pages in one step

Tags: django-cms

In django-cms, if I have done a lot of changes in different pages and added new pages, is there any alterative to clicking "publish" on each page separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah there is a management command just for this scenario.

```
cms publisher-publish
```

It accepts the following options

- `--unpublished`: set to publish all drafts, including unpublished ones; if not set, only already published pages will be republished.
- `-l, --language`: specify a language code to publish pages in only one language; if not specified, this command publishes all page languages;
- `--site`: specify a site id to publish pages for specified site only; if not specified, this command publishes pages for all sites;

Examples;

```
#publish drafts for public pages in all languages
cms publisher-publish

#publish all drafts in all pages
cms publisher-publish --unpublished

#publish drafts for public pages in deutsch
cms publisher-publish --language=de

#publish all drafts in deutsch
cms publisher-publish --unpublished --language=de

#publish all drafts in deutsch, but only for site with id=2
cms publisher-publish --unpublished --language=de --site=2
```

The full docs for this can be found here; http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/cli.html#cms-publisher-publish